# Crop an area of oversized image to what is currently showing onscreen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I have an oversized image loaded in a image view that goes out of bounds both vertically and horizontally.

The end user can scroll around the image (the oversized imageview is in a scrollview) and when they find an area that they like I would like to crop out the area of the image that is shown on the screen. (much like a screenshot but only of the imageview.image I'm then going to put that into a different Imageview.

I can't seem to work out how to accomplish the "screenshot" of the area of the image view's image that is currently showing on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` to create a subimage of the displayed image. Use `contentOffset` and the scrollViews `bounds` to create the rect from which you want to create the image.

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentOffset.y, CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(scrollView.bounds));
CGImageRef subImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([originalImage CGImage], rect);
```

If you zoom your scrollView you will need to take the zoomLevel into account too.

Comment: I ended up going a different route that required less calculation as I do zoom in/out. Thank you regardless for your effort. I'm actually going to look into CGImageCreateWithImageInRect to see how it works, might run into something I Can use that for. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following code to achieve what I was looking for to grab the image. Thank you to Karl for his input and a thank you to iNoob whom answer to a previous question [Located here on StackOverflow][1] I used for mine.

Just use the below code to take a "screenshot" just set anything you don't want in the image to.hidden = True; before the code to hide it from the screenshot and set them to .Hidden = FALSE; after the code to bring them back.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *theImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```